# pandas load in excel sheets and set to different dataframes

Tags: excel, pandas, load

I have an excel workbook with sheets named A, B and C

I wanted to load all sheets and set the sheets to different dataframes, is this possible?

This is what I have so far;

```
sheets=['A','B','C']

for s in sheets:
      df_+s=pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=s)
```

so the output would be 3 dataframes named, df_A, df_B and df_C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dfs = pd.read_excel(file, None)
```

would return a dict of dataframes. The dataframes from sheet A is `dfs['A']`, sheet B is `dfs['B']` and sheet C is `dfs['C']`.

Comment: what does None refer to ?

Comment: @fred.schwartz `sheet_name=None`, so requests all sheets.

Comment: @anky_91 Thanks, quite right. I've edited the answer.